# What is the difference between trustpool and trustpoint on Cisco IOS?

Tags: cisco-ios

On Cisco IOS, there is **trustpool** and there is **trustpoint**. I have seen imported certificates in either of the two. And it seems SSL connection works when either location has the certificate it needs. What are the differences between them?

```
Router#show crypto pki ?  
  ...
  trustpoints   Show trustpoints
  trustpool     Show certificates in trustpool
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TrustPool is the pool (the list or collection) of all installed non-self-signed certs.

A TrustPoint is a binding point for a specific certificate, to tie to a specific service (such as for remote-access VPN).

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a bit more about the TrustPoint? Do you have an example of a trustpoint tied to a specific service?

Comment: @someuser If you check out the Cisco article [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/public-key-infrastructure-pki/200339-Configure-ASA-SSL-Digital-Certificate-I.html#anc7) it walks you through the process of creating the TrustPoint, and tying the certificate (TrustPoint) to the AnyConnect service, using the CLI. It also has instructions for doing the same via ASDM, if you like.  The TrustPool is built-in, so you don't do anything to configure that.

Comment: Thanks. To put it in something that I can understand. Trustpool is a collection of certificates which the device can trust, similar to a browser's CA pool. Trustpoint can serve the same purpose, with the addition that it has a reference identifier which can be referenced by certain feature, such as HTTP server or VPN/crypto, when a specific certificate needs to be specified.

Comment: @someuser That seems accurate enough.